Next.js pages router, how to import code that needs to be run by the client?
I need to use google map in my project, I use @googlemaps/extended-component-library library.@googlemaps/extended-component-library


import '@googlemaps/extended-component-library/api_loader.js';
import '@googlemaps/extended-component-library/split_layout.js';
import '@googlemaps/extended-component-library/place_overview.js';

export default function Gmap() {
    return (
        <>
            <gmpx-api-loader key="MY_KEY"></gmpx-api-loader>
                <gmpx-place-overview slot="fixed" place="ChIJ39Y-tdg1fYcRQcZcBb499do"></gmpx-place-overview>
                <gmp-map
                    center="37.4220656,-122.0840897"
                    zoom="10"
                    map-id="DEMO_MAP_ID"
                    style={{ height: "400px" }}
                ></gmp-map>

            <script
                src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap&v=beta"
                defer
            ></script>
        </>
    );
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



When I import it like this, next will report the error document is not defined
Is there any way to import it only on the client side?  I don't want to use @googlemaps/extended-component-library/react

you can mark this page to client component by specifying "use client".
refer : official docs here 
"use client" in client component

How to use it in pages router
